# CSS Stylesheet not linking to HTML file

Tags: html, css

I've tried almost every Fix people recommend but it's not helping for some reason.
I'm trying to change my site's font to Sans-serif but the CSS Spreadsheet won't link to the Html.

The code on my Stylesheet is:

```
body {font-family: sans-serif;}
```

And to link it to my html after my title I have:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/My-first-stylesheet.css"/>
```

If you know a way to fix this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You're going to have to share some code or at least a link to what isn't working.

Comment: I did share code. wasn't appearing though, fixed it.

Comment: do you have href+ or href= ?

Comment: replace `href+` with `href=`

Comment: switched it to href= and it didn't help either for some reason.

Comment: Get familiar with browser tools (f12 in most browsers). Using the network tab of browser tools you will see if you style-sheet has been found. Inspecting elements will show you what styles are being applied and what is being over-ridden. You may have a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Also remember to flush your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking your css file with this syntax:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/My-first-stylesheet.css" />
```

This requires that your CSS file is relative to your HTML file though

```
== file structure ==

(html file)
CSS (folder)
    My-first-stylesheet.css
```

Comment: HTML still isn't in Sans-serif for some reason.

Comment: Can you please update your original question with the CSS in your My-first-stylesheet where you are setting the font to sans-serif?

Comment: change `Body` to `body`

Comment: You also need an equals, `=` to link your CSS in your HTML file, see my answer

Comment: oh, okay will do.

Comment: Where would I put the = at?

Comment: Like this: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/My-first-stylesheet.css"/>`

Comment: It still hasn't changed from serif.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `href+"CSS/My-first-stylesheet.css"` to  `href="CSS/My-first-stylesheet.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
body {font-family: sans-serif !important;}
```

It could just be a specificity problem.

Comment: Be VERY cautious using `!important` 
 :https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the entire local path of your stylesheet to "href".